# How to split a number into sign, integer and fractional?

Tags: python, string, list, split, numbers

sorry if my formatting is a bit weird. I am not quite used to formatting code on this site.
I'm given a decimal number in a string format. I want to be able to split this number up into its sign, integer part and the fractional part.

Example:

```
INPUT: -1223.231

OUTPUT: sign: - integer: 12 fraction: 231
```

My code below works for only fractional negative or positive numbers. I run into indexing errors when I try to use my code on a whole number such as 1234 or -1234. I believe the issue is when I try to split on a whole number I can't. 
To clarify I would like the output of a whole number to look like this:

```
INPUT: 1234

OUTPUT: sign: + integer: 1234 fraction: 0
```

Any help on how I could make my code also split up whole numbers?
Thanks in advance.

```
decimal_string = '-1223.231'
if(decimal_string[0]=="-"):
    sign="-"
    splitValue = decimal_string.split('.')
    print("sign: " + sign + " integer: " + splitValue[0][1:] +" fraction: " + splitValue[1])

elif(decimal_string=="0"):
    print("sign: + integer: " + decimal_string[0:] + " fraction: 0")

else:
    sign="+"
    splitValue = decimal_string.split('.')
    int_part = int(splitValue[0])
    decimal_part = int(splitValue[1])
    print("sign: " + sign + " integer: " + splitValue[0] +" fraction: " + splitValue[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
s = "-1223.231"
s1 = "-1234"
s2 = "1234"
def getVal(s):
    sign = "+"
    fraction = 0
    integer = None
    if s.startswith("-"):                     #Check if input is negative
        sign = "-"
        s = s.replace("-", "")
    if "." in s:                              #Check if input has decimal
        integer, fraction = s.split(".")
    else:
        integer = s
    return sign, integer, fraction

print("sign: {0} ,integer: {1},fraction: {2}".format(*getVal(s)))
print("sign: {0} ,integer: {1},fraction: {2}".format(*getVal(s1)))
print("sign: {0} ,integer: {1},fraction: {2}".format(*getVal(s2)))
```

**Output:**

```
sign: - ,integer: 1223,fraction: 231
sign: - ,integer: 1234,fraction: 0
sign: + ,integer: 1234,fraction: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help was very useful!